# How to properly terminate or close a background task in aiohttp application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm writing an app using aiohttp and asyncio. One of the parts of the app is supposed to continuously monitor a specific device for incoming data. It works as expected except that I cannot close the app if no data comes from the device. Here's a stipped version of the code:

```py
async def background_tasks(app):
    app['scaner_listener'] = asyncio.create_task(watchscaner(app))
    yield
    app['scaner_listener'].cancel()
    await app['scaner_listener']

async def shutdown(app):
    try:
        app['scaner_listener'].cancel()
    except BaseException as Err:
        logging.error(f'Error in the shutdown cleanup: {type(Err)} {Err.args}')


def main():
    app = web.Application()
    app.cleanup_ctx.append(background_tasks)
    app.on_shutdown.append(shutdown)
    web.run_app(app)
```

The code above is basically a copy-paste from official documentation while the function below is the one that (supposedly) causes the problem:

```py
async def watchscaner(app):
    try:
        async with aiofiles.open("/dev/scaner0", "r") as dev:
            buffer = ""
            b = await dev.read(1)  # line 1
            while b:               # line 2
                if b == "\n":
                    buffer = ""
                elif b == "\x00":
                    if len(buffer) > 0:
                        logging.info(f"Scanned {buffer=}")
                        buffer = ""
                else:
                    buffer += b
                b = await dev.read(1)  # line 3
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        logging.warning('Cancelled error')
    finally:
        logging.info('Finally came here')
```

Also I tried the following approach for the commented "line1-2"

```py
    while True:
        b = await dev.read(1)
```

with or without the "line 3".

In all the cases, the application works fine, and the data from scanner are received without any problems. The only problem is - when I exit the app, the watchscanner task is still waiting for any incoming data from `/dev/scaner0` and exits only after that.

It looks like I'm not awaiting the data properly, but this is my assumption only.

Any suggestions are highgly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe its aiofiles. You could test by writing your own scanner read thread. See [aiofiles issue](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles/issues/157)

Comment: Thank you. I was suspecting something like that after I did a whole bunch of other tests, but its nice to have this kind of confirmation.